# How to add an edge ring around a hole

Tags: modeling

[image]

What is the easiest way to add/extrude an edge loop around the hole in the first image to make it like the second image?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to using bevel (@RobinBetts answer), you can also use **Inset**.

In face selection select all your geometry minus the ring of faces inside the hole, then inset <kbd>I</kbd>. This gives you loops on both sides of the hole.

Comment: Counter-intuitive, and ingeneous. You learn something every day...

Comment: this works brilliantly, thx

Answer (score 2):

Select the loop, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> bevel it, with 2 segments, and a profile of 1. This will give you a bevel with the original loop intact, the new loop you want, flush to the outer surface, and one you may or may not want around the recess. You can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> dissolve the inner one away, if you like.

You can follow this up with a <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> slide on the new loop(s), using <kbd>E</kbd> to make the slide parallel to one or other of the surrounding loops, and <kbd>F</kbd> to decide which.

Comment: Thank you, this and the solution posted by Jaroslav Jerryno Novotny work great.

Answer (score 0):

Scale the hole up using <kbd>Shift+Y</kbd> (image one), select its two edge loops. Use extrude + scale to the **inside** (image two) and bridge the loops. The second scale is the ScaleOne<sup>-1</sup>. Scaling up remember to keep the loop within your face.
[image: Hole scaled up]

[image: E+S]

Comment: I don't really see why this got a downvote.. it's straightforward, and precise? Strictly, it's not very general, I suppose? It needs the pipe to be straight?

Answer (score -1):

Select your hole (the cylindrical edge loop) completly and press <kbd>E</kbd> and <kbd>S</kbd> to scale. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> once or twice to contrain the scale axis correctly. Then type in the amount of scale you want and remember it. Next press <kbd>Numpad +</kbd> and scale by 1 divided by your remembered scale. You may need to take out an calculator for that. Hope this workflow helps you